# Converting a large HTML file in PDF format

Tags: php, html, pdf

after some research about this subject (FPDI, FPDF... and so on)
I try to find a solution for converting a large HTML File (about 25k lines)
in PDF format.

Open sources libraires I tested were not efficient, took a very long time to do this job for a poor result :/

Could you tell me if someone had this feature to do with PHP and what could be a solution ?

Regards.

Comment: This question is probably better asked over at software recommendations:  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question is probably better asked over at software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Could you give me some information about the content? I have been successful converting a lot html to PDF so far (and then sending these by fax).

Without knowing more, what I can recommend is to make sure that you write all type of CSS styling inline on the tags as in  etc.

Comment: Well, thanks for your first answer. The HTML file content many things, like classics html tags (title, span, div...), a large amount of chart creating by GD library and many JTable. Hope it will help for ansanswering :)